# HTML - What is the <page> tag doing?

Tags: html, css

I've been playing with getting a HTML document to display in A4 size and using the code in this codepen works perfectly:

https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/LFAes

CSS

```
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}

page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }

page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
}
```

HTML

```
<page size="A4"></page>
```

However, I'm not sure how or why declaring page and page [size information] in CSS allows you to use the  tag in HTML.   In fact, I can find any reference to a HTML page tag anywhere.

Can someone please explain how the code is working in the codepen?   Thanks in advance

Comment: This should not be confused with CSS's `@page` which defines page rules for print.

Comment: The answers are good, however one should note that even as a custom HTML5 element, it's incorrect. Custom HTML elements *must* contain a dash (hyphen) to be valid. So `<page>` is never valid, but `<page-page>`  or `<home-page>` would both be valid HTML5 custom elements.

Comment: Just to say that I wanted something that worked so I used the code in the codepen (disclaimer: not my codepen).

Thanks for the feedback everyone

Comment: see also [How are non-standard tags processed by browser?](/q/42995887/11107541). your assumption that the tag somehow becomes meaningful due to the CSS you wrote is wrong.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I do not believe that `<page>` is an actual HTML element.

When the browser sees this, it probably thinks it is getting old and missing out on new inventions that didn't exist when the browser was released.

In that case it is treated like a `<div>`, and CSS rules still apply.

But really it's best to stick to elements that really exist, instead of pretending they will some day, because in the future the implementations of newly created tags could be different than you expect.

It would have been better to be written as `<div class="page" data-size="A4">` with the CSS looking for `div.page` and `div.page[data-size="A4"]`.

Comment: Both answers are great, but this is the most appropriate thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't HTML. This just takes advantage of the fact that, in order to facilitate future expansions to the language, browsers allow unknown elements to be targeted with CSS and JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about HTML5 tags [HERE](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/all-html-tags.htm)

If you want use HTML5 you should replace `<page></page>` with `<div>` or `<section>`. Page tag doesnt exist!

with it you can style your HTML with

`section {
   "your style"
  }
section[size="A4"] {
  "your style"
  }`

Answer (score -1):

Hate to necro this post, but the accepted answer isn't completely correct. For the sake of others...

> I'm not sure how or why declaring page and page [size information] in CSS allows you to use the tag in HTML. In fact, I can find any reference to a HTML page tag anywhere. Can someone please explain how the code is working in the codepen?

HTML is based on XML and older established formatting. That is in essence what HTML is, a standardized format that the web uses; see https://www.w3.org/
This is the reason you can create a website with notepad. It's just syntax...

The answer to your question is understanding that HTML is simply a big character string and the code processing that string looks inside `<` and `>` to give it instructions. It doesn't care what is inside of `< >` and you are not required to use tags from the w3 html specifications.

Now, having said that... you might want to adhere to those specs for ADL, SOC, etc, to ensure your users have the best experience if they are disabled or your site/software has to interact with other software; even the browser. Hence, the very reason for the specifications.

---

But you can use any word you want for a tag.

```
    <page>
        <mysection>
            <yesterday>Something something</yesterday>
            <today>Something something</today>
        </mysection>
    </page>

    // javascript access
    let page = document.getElementById("page");
    page.style.backgroundColor = orange;

    // CSS
    page {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

- Take for example Vue or any other framework. You can use whatever tag you want as a name for a component: `<child-comp></child-comp>` see https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-13
- Side Note: A lot of frameworks will fail html validation because they use custom tags. Take any vue, react or angular website and run them through https://validator.w3.org/ to see for yourself.
- Another example is attributes. There are a standardized list of attributes for each tag ie `<input type="number" max="1000" />`, type and max. Yet, that doesn't prevent you from using your own attributes.

```
    // Attribute example
    <input currency currencydecimalplaces="2"/>

    // jQuery or JavaScript can access it
    $('[currency]').on('keyup', function(){
        let decimalPlaces = $(this).attr('currencydecimalplaces');
        this.value = this.value.toFixed(decimalPlaces);
    });

    // CSS can access it
    [currency] {
        position: relative;
    }
    [currency]:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "$";
        top: 4px;
        left: -8px;
    }
```

Conclusion is you can use whatever you want, but to be browser safe and user friendly, it's best to use the defined specifications from w3.

Hope that helps.