# How to print an HTML table that perfectly fit A4 sheet

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, html-table

I have a simply html page with a big table. I would like to print so that it fit perfectly with width and height in the A4 sheet. It's in landscape.

When I try to print looks like the width is automatically adjusted but not the height and every time I print there is a white page.

Also when I make font-size bigger, the height of the cell changes... how can I avoid this? (like overflow:hidden for the width)

This is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="referto.css" />
      <title>Referto</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <page size="A4">
      <table>
         ...
      </table>
    </page>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {

}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

td {
  font-size: 2mm;
  border-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.t1 {border-top: 0.1mm solid}
.b1 {border-bottom: 0.1mm solid}
.l1 {border-left: 0.1mm solid}
.r1 {border-right: 0.1mm solid}

.t2 {border-top: 0.2mm solid}
.b2 {border-bottom: 0.2mm solid}
.l2 {border-left: 0.2mm solid}
.r2 {border-right: 0.2mm solid}

.t3 {border-top: 0.3mm solid}
.b3 {border-bottom: 0.3mm solid}
.l3 {border-left: 0.3mm solid}
.r3 {border-right: 0.3mm solid}

.t4 {border-top: 0.4mm solid}
.b4 {border-bottom: 0.4mm solid}
.l4 {border-left: 0.4mm solid}
.r4 {border-right: 0.4mm solid}

.t5 {border-top: 0.5mm solid}
.b5 {border-bottom: 0.5mm solid}
.l5 {border-left: 0.5mm solid}
.r5 {border-right: 0.5mm solid}

.t6 {border-top: 0.6mm solid}
.b6 {border-bottom: 0.6mm solid}
.l6 {border-left: 0.6mm solid}
.r6 {border-right: 0.6mm solid}

.t7 {border-top: 0.7mm solid}
.b7 {border-bottom: 0.7mm solid}
.l7 {border-left: 0.7mm solid}
.r7 {border-right: 0.7mm solid}

.t8 {border-top: 0.8mm solid}
.b8 {border-bottom: 0.8mm solid}
.l8 {border-left: 0.8mm solid}
.r8 {border-right: 0.8mm solid}

page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 297mm;
  height: 210mm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196261/html-what-is-the-page-tag-doing

Answer (score 0):

Try to add media queries also for

```
@media screen and (max-width: ) {}
@media screen and (max-height: ){}
```