# How to print small and large bills within A4 page in on click?

Tags: html, css, printing, printing-web-page

Client want to print all bills in one click. All bills comes together to single web-page and they mixup with each-other.

I tried few things as using page tag with css page `[size="A4"]` but nothing fruitful yet :(

```
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;

}
@media print {
  page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
        width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  }
}
```

How to collapse each invoice data within same A4 page?? please help

```
<page size="A4"> INVOICE DATA which comes more or less than A4 size </page>
```

Comment: Do you have some _sample data_ where we can see, what happens.

Comment: if there is small bill which covers half page next bill starts from half same page, not printing on next page. whereas, same for big bills which take place on next page and next bill start in middle of the page.

Comment: I understand, I will test, some stuff here. btw. check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/37196261/1679286
And on which browser should this work IE 11 , firefox, Edge, Chrome,.... ? probably all ;-)

Comment: btw.: does your html look like `<page> ....all invoices.... </page>` or `<page> invoice1 </page><page> invoice2 </page>...`

Comment: I Chrome it works, but you would have to set the borders for printing to **none**

Comment: no its like <page> invoice1</page> <page>invoice2</page>

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: Thank you @winner_joiner for helping out, would pls answer with the code... it will b more easy

Answer (score 0):

Finally that code work for me :) yey

```
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;

}
@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```