# How to print page in two columns?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML page:

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <page size="A5"></page size="A5">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <page size="A5"></page size="A5">
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

When I try to print this document in album mode A4, I am not getting one sheet divided in two parts A5.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all I don't think that  is an actual HTML tag.

Try to change the  tag to an  with the required css. Open up the code snippet in full screen to see the result.

```css
.page {
  background-color: black;
  height: 21cm;
  width: 14.8cm;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="page"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="page"></div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS has provided the `grid` display so outer package like bootstrap isn't that necessary for this task. You can also customize the gap between 2 pages by using the attribute `gap` under the `.row` style in the CSS. Also [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196261/html-what-is-the-page-tag-doing) may help you on building paper-like appearance.

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
}

page[size="A5"] {
  width: 14.8cm;
  height: 21cm;
}

page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md-6">
                <page size="A5"></page size="A5">
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-6">
                <page size="A5"></page size="A5">
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```